# Is there a function to select and show certain features only in print composer?

Tags: qgis

I have a feature layer with points. I have three pages in my print composer. On one of my pages, I only want to show points that fall within a certain value range. First, I tried locking the style on the pages where I want to display all my points.

[image]

Then, I went to the Query Builder of the layer I want to select points from, and I created an expression to display only points from a range:

[image]

The problem is that this selection modifies the points shown on all my pages in print composer, even the ones where I locked the layers and style for layers. The only alternative solution I can think of is to select the points I want to show, create a new feature layer with those selected points, and then show that feature layer on my page in print composer. However I'd like to know if there's another way to do this without creating a new feature layer each time I want to filter the points I show in print composer.

Answer (score 0):

There's another way. The points change because when you define a query, basically you define what features will be loaded to the project. So if you use categorized symbology you can define that some feature will be not displayed, but they will stay loaded in the project.
Here you can find how to use this type of symbology: [Classifying Nominal Data](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/vector_classification/classification.html#basic-fa-classifying-nominal-data)